# Getting wrong when installing tensorflow from source

Tags: installation, tensorflow

I had been trying to install tensorflow for a few day. However, cuda 7.5 is the version that tensorflow r0.10.0 supports default. So I can only install it from source. But I came after the following problem which bother me a lot.

.....
INFO: Reading options for 'clean' from /home/lhx/tensorflow-r0.10/tools/bazel.rc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --force_python=py2 --host_force_python=py2 --python2_path=/usr/bin/python --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --define=allow_oversize_protos=true --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python --spawn_strategy=standalone --genrule_strategy=standalone
Unrecognized option: --host_force_python=py2
ERROR: /home/lhx/tensorflow-r0.10/WORKSPACE:18:6: First argument of load() is a path, not a label. It should start with a single slash if it is an absolute path..
ERROR: /home/lhx/tensorflow-r0.10/WORKSPACE:22:6: First argument of load() is a path, not a label. It should start with a single slash if it is an absolute path..
ERROR: WORKSPACE file could not be parsed.
ERROR: package contains errors: third_party/boringssl.
ERROR: no such package 'external': Package 'external' contains errors.
Configuration finished

I just can't figure out what is going wrong and I have been trying for so long.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar errors when my bazel was too outdated. You can try newer bazel version.